# Producing Shadow Indexes in Google Earth Engine using maximum values from a ImageCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, spatial-index, shadow

I'm trying to generate a Shadow Index using the maximum values from a image composite (ImageCollection). Here is the link with the code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/67b8fb1318fe0163fca15b71a8f600af

The code works well when applied to a single image, but when I use the same code for the composite it generates an total black output:

[image]

Here is the code:

```java
// Sentinel-2 BCI script
var S2_display = {bands: ['B3', 'B4', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 3000};
var si_palette = 'FFFFFF, CE7E45, DF923D, F1B555, FCD163, 99B718, 74A901, 66A000, 529400, ' + '3E8601, 207401, 056201, 004C00, 023B01, 012E01, 011D01, 011301';
function addnd(input) {
  var si = input.expression(
    '(1-BLUE)*(1-GREEN)*(1- RED)', {
    GREEN:input.select('B3'),
    RED:input.select('B4'),
    BLUE:input.select('B2')
  
    })
    .pow(1/3)
    .uint16()
    .rename('si');
  return input.addBands(si);
}

//Import shp
var NUT = ee.FeatureCollection(table)
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2', 'Viseu'));

print(NUT);
//Jan2019
// January 2019 S2 imagery
var S2_Jan = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
  .filterBounds(NUT)
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-01-06')
  .map(addnd);

print(S2_Jan);

var si_Jan = S2_Jan.select('si').max().clip(NUT);

Map.addLayer(si_Jan, {max: 10000} ,'si Jan 2019');


//var bsi_Jan_16b_Centro = bsi_Jan.multiply(10000).int16();

Export.image.toDrive({
image: si_Jan,
description: 'BSI_Centro_Jan_2019',
scale: 10,
fileFormat: 'TIF',
maxPixels: 10000000000000,
region: NUT,
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

With other indexes the composite works well (using for example the max values of NDVI).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by multiplying the bands by 10000:

'(10000-BLUE)*(10000-GREEN)*(10000- RED)', {
GREEN:input.select('B3'),
RED:input.select('B4'),
BLUE:input.select('B2')